# MVC gridview resize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, width

I have a gridview and I want it to be 100% width:

```
settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
```

But I don't want to allow the user to change the width of the columns or the gridview.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up your grid in your partial, you can access the [ColumnResizeMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesColumnResizeModeEnumtopic) enumerator of the `SettingsBehavior` property:

```
 var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.SettingsBehavior.ColumnResizeMode = ColumnResizeMode.NextColumn;
}
```